# Bind the make command to a shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, makefile-mode

I use `Emacs` under Ubuntu.

I would like to bind the `make` command to a shortcut, so that `makefile` could be launched. If the compilation fails, I would the error message to be shown in a sub-window or the message bar; otherwise, I would all the sub-windows to be closed except the one containing the main text.

Does anyone know how to realize that? Also which shortcut should be chosen?

Comment: Why not just bind `compile` to whatever key you'd like?  `compile-command` is 'make -k' by default.

Comment: Or, even better, use `recompile` instead of  `compile`. That way you skip the confirmation step.

Comment: Like deprecated said, just bind the recompile command, and set compile-command somewhere in your init file.  F5 or F7 are pretty common shortcuts for most IDEs.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but, when I run `M-x compile` it uses my dir vars, and run make accordingly. If I use `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'compile)`, the compile command run is not the same (asks complete different questions, probably related to the major mode). How to specify the exact 'built-in' compile method?

Answer (score 5):

One possibility (based on an original suggestion by Kyle Meyer) is

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") 'recompile)
```

Then you can type `C-c m`, which will first offer to save the current buffer if necessary, and then will run the command `make -k` in the directory containing the associated file.  The `-k` switch causes make to try to keep going even if some commands fail.  In case you want to modify this, you can type `C-u C-c m` and you will get the chance to edit the compilation command in the minibuffer first.  The edited command will then be remembered on a per-buffer basis.

Any compilation errors will be shown in a dedicated buffer (called `*compilation*`) and you can either click on these with the mouse (to jump to the relevant point in the source file) or use `C-x backtick` to cycle through them (sorry, I can't work out how to type a literal backtick inside backticks!).  The compilation buffer is not shown if no errors occur but you get a notification in the echo area when compilation is complete.

Of course, you can use any other key of your choice instead of `C-c m` - I chose that for the mnemonic `m` = "make" and because the `C-c letter` keys are reserved for the end-user, so there is little risk of collision.

Answer (score 1):

So the global set key to recompile is the first way to go. Now we can try another option, more interactive and visual, which is `helm-make` by abo-abo, a prolific emacs lisp developer: https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make

With the command `helm-make-projectile` you will have a nice helm buffer which suggests the targets of the makefile, that it will find at your project root directory (handy). Choose one and it calls `compile`.

Install it with

```
package-install RET helm-make RET
```

(you need [MELPA](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/MELPA))

Note: and [this package](https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/make-menu) is similar, but it's mine, it displays a menu with the Makefile targets, and it isn't in melpa. To try it copy it in a buffer and call `M-x eval-buffer`.